# Working with twitter api 1.1

Tags: php, json, twitter

I recently worked with twitter api 1.1 to retrieve tweet results for a search term.
My observations are, unless we use search term with a preceding %23, it didnt work. And also, the only output we get is in JSON.
Can we get the output in the form of XML or array.
Converting resulting JSON to array(I needed array for processing), it took a while to convert which compromises with process time.
Is there anyway to use twitter api 1 and get results?
Also, any way to convert json to array faster than json_decode?

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets Looks like you can only get JSON back. They also say it's rather flaky, not everything will be returned and suggest this article: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

Comment: Thank you Jacobs, will check that.